# Scheduling android graphics events

Tags: android, video

I asked this question over in the Android Developer's user group, last week.  Nobody responded, so I thought I'd ask it over here.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to schedule video events to happen at an exact clock time?  I've been thinking about an application that would require two adjacent phones to display the same thing at exactly the same time.  I'm wondering what that granularity of "exactly" is going to be.

I've done some testing on a couple of devices and it seems that the delay between an invalidate and the subsequent redraw can be as much 16ms.  Perhaps I can do better with OpenGL?

Ideas?  Anyone?

Comment: I got an answer to this, from none other then Chet Hasse.  It appears that (... and I guess this part should be obvious) refresh rate determined by the hardware.  It might be possible to get notification, from the hardware, that a redraw is occurring.  That would make it possible to synchronize on the redraw boundary.  Scheduling things that happen at intervals smaller than the refresh interval, though, is very hard.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL itself is capable of very high framerates (unless I am mistaken). What I can tell you is that plenty of games have been written to run and maintain 30 frames per second. That's one frame every 3.33ms. At that speed, the change should be imperceptible to the human eye, or so I've heard (the estimate limit is 5ms).

However, there is a major difference between what OpenGL can do, and what the device running OpenGL can do. Again, Unless I am mistaken, you should be able to instruct OpenGL to run at 200 frames per second. The caveat is that if the machine you are running the animation on can't handle that framerate, it will either frame-skip or lag, and in either case will hog the processor and GPU like no other.

Again, as I don't know the specifics, I can only guess, but I would think that this is less of an issue with OpenGL vs the other leading brand, and more of an issue of the devices you are trying to sync. With the right code, a proven framework, two powerful machines, and high-speed data transfer capability (read: LAN at the least), there is no reason why you shouldn't be able to sync up the video. If any of these things are not the case, all bets are off.

-Cody